# Re-applying after a refused visa application

Tags: visas, schengen, belgium, visa-refusals

I applied for a Schengen visa from Belgium and it got refused. My visa type was friends/family visit and I applied for one and a half month. However, I really want to visit Amsterdam, Belgium and Spain and my maximum stay will be in Belgium. And this time I am applying for just 15 days. My question is can I apply as a tourist this time without any sponsorship letter or invitation letter like I did before.

**Update:**

Thanks for the reply. Actually the guy who sent me his sponsorship letter and invitation letter is working on site from India and is in Belgium for 1 year, so he has temporary residency permit. And in my refusal letter they stated that guarantor does not have permanent residential permit. That is why even if I send my additional documents like my bank statement (which was not asked although because my relative was sponsoring me, but still they mentioned it in the refusal letter) it will still get rejected.

This is a reason I want to apply as a tourist this time because I just want to see the city and come back. Also, I called the VFS centre and the customer care said that it is not a problem because even if I re-apply my application will be considered as a fresh application. But I don't trust these embassy people… Thats is why I am concerned.

Comment: You can always try. Maybe try another country since Belgium has by far the highest refusal rates in Schengen: http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/overview_of_schengen_visa_statistics_en.pdf

Comment: Do you have any comments from ambassy why your visa was rejected?

Answer (score 1):

All Schengen consulates will have a record of the refusal in their databases. Officers at the Belgium consulate might even remember it or have some file about it. Applying immediately for a visa under another category, without any change in your situation and without submitting extra documentation is going to look bad and is likely to lead to a new rejection.

You *can* apply again if you want, and [sometimes it works](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36593/need-to-understand-why-my-schengen-visa-was-rejected) but you need to be very careful. If you don't have a strong case, you will just waste your money and make your next application even more difficult.