# Validity of Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I want to apply for a Schengen visa for multiple countries from London. My travel plan is Belgium then Switzerland and last is Paris.

What will be the validity of the visa I will get if first port of entry is Belgium? Do I get a 6 months visa validity or less than that?

Comment: Note that depending on how long you are planning to stay in each country, it might in principle be necessary to apply to the Swiss or the French consulate instead of the Belgian one.

Answer (score 2):

It's largely up to the consulate processing your application. The *Handbook for the processing of visa applications* recommends issuing a visa valid for the duration of the trip (as documented in the application) plus a grace period of fifteen days (to make things simpler, in case you get delayed). [But it even happens that consulates issue visas that are too short for the intended trip](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37006/got-a-schengen-visa-thats-too-short-for-my-trip-can-i-stay-one-more-day).

Since you are presumably a resident in the UK, you might however get lucky and obtain a [six-month multiple entry visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/can-i-have-multiple-schengen-visas-for-future-travels-in-my-passport) without requesting it. If you have been to the Schengen area before and justify a need to travel frequently, you could even get a visa valid for up to five years.

No matter the validity of the visa, you will not be allowed to stay [more than 90 days in the area in any 180-day period](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule).

Comment: A few years ago, my wife got a Norwegian visa that started the day AFTER her intended arrival date and ended exactly on the intended departure date.  She had to go back to the embassy to get it sorted.